# dynamic carousels (jQuery) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a dynamic carousel using jquery, but for some reason the code is not running. I would like to generate carousel div's based on the number of images I have in the var Images array in the script. Can you guys correct my code below?

Here is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
 /* BOOTSTRAP 3.x GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}



/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}



/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 400px;
  background-color:#555;
}
.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 400px;
}



/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Pad the edges of the mobile views a bit */
.marketing {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}
.featurette {
  padding-top: 120px; /* Vertically center images part 1: add padding above and below text. */
  overflow: hidden; /* Vertically center images part 2: clear their floats. */
}
.featurette-image {
  margin-top: -120px; /* Vertically center images part 3: negative margin up the image the same amount of the padding to center it. */
}

/* Give some space on the sides of the floated elements so text doesn't run right into it. */
.featurette-image.pull-left {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.featurette-image.pull-right {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}



/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* Remve the edge padding needed for mobile */
  .marketing {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -90px; /* Negative margin to pull up carousel. 90px is roughly margins and height of navbar. */
  }
  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

}

 
 
 
 </style>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner"> </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"> </a> </div>
<!-- /.carousel -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery/jQuery-hm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" >
 
  $(document).ready(function(){  
     var images = [
   "http://placehold.it/1500X500",
     "http://placehold.it/1500X500",
     "http://placehold.it/1500X500"
     ];
  
  for(var i=0 ; i< images.length ; i++) {
    $('<div class="item"><img src="'+images[i]+'"><div class="carousel-caption"></div>   </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
    $('<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'+i+'"></li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')

  }
  $('.item').first().addClass('active');
  $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
  $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel();
});
 
 
 
 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me fix the mistake I am making.

Comment: what is mean not working? plus, you had multiple jquery reference, which is not correct and might cause issue

Comment: When I run it, nothing appears. Its just blank  @Se0ng11

Comment: first, remove your redundant jquery, u had total of 5 jquery which is conflict with each other, second, check ur browser console(f12), if there is any specific error